# Setting up https connection to my transmission web UI

Tags: pi-3

I have transmission service running on my pi and i want to setup https connection to it, like-

```
https://pi:9091/transmission/web/
```

How can i do this? Please suggest.

Comment: I didnt find a tag for transmission. If any of you finds, please move it to the respective tag.

Comment: Are you trying to connect this for access remotely, over the Internet?

Comment: Besides being off-topic because the question is completely non-related, visit [whathaveyoutried.com](http://whathaveyoutried.com). It's not about developers only.

Comment: Did you click on menu - Preferences - [Enable Web Client](http://10629-presscdn-0-58.pagely.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/pictures/2011/03/Transmission_Prefs.png) yet?

Comment: Alan, your question is extremely open ended, and is likely answerable from a simple google search. What have you tried so far? Have you followed a guide and gotten stuck? Do you have an error message?

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev: I have already enabled the webclient and im currenly connected to `http://200.0.0.3:9091/transmission/web/`.

Comment: @jacobm001: I tried searching in google for this, but was unable to find a solution and hence posted the question here.

Comment: All, i feel that if people dont have an answer for this, this post can very well be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

`transmission` doesn't support HTTPS web interface, and as far as I know there are no plans to add such a feature. To get the web interface work with HTTPS, you'll have to install an HTTPS-capable proxy, or a web server with proxy capabilities, like `nginx`. Install it with `apt-get install nginx` and follow [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/226027/395993) to make it work with `transmission`.

You'll also need an SSL certificate to verify the identity of your server. You can generate a certificate yourself (as the answer I linked to describes), but you'll have to check the certificate manually every time you connect. A better solution would be to obtain a free SSL certificate that your browser could validate automatically, e.g. from https://letsencrypt.org/.